# Convergence of the series: $\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{(-1)^n\arctan (n)}{n+n^{1/2}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \tan^{-1}(n)/(n+(n)^{1/2}).$$ 
I know that the series is not absolutely converges.
I want to prove using Alternative test. I don't know how to prove that  sequence  $ tan^{-1}n/(n+(n)^{1/2})$ is decreasing sequence.

Comment: Show that the function $ \ \frac{\arctan x}{x \ + \ x^{1/2}} \ $ has a negative derivative, at least for  $  \ x \  $ greater than some constant $ \ N \ $ .

Comment: I tried to that's method.. However i could not prove...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may write
$$
\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{(-1)^n\arctan (n)}{n+n^{1/2}}=\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n+n^{1/2}}-\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n+n^{1/2}}\arctan \left(\frac1n\right).
$$ The first series on the right hand side is convergent by the alternate series test, the second series is absolutely convergent, since as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n+n^{1/2}}\arctan \left(\frac1n\right)\right|\leq
\frac{1}{n+n^{1/2}}\arctan \left(\frac1n\right) \sim \frac{1}{n^{2}}.
$$ Your initial series is then convergent.

Comment: Why first equation satisfies?

Comment: @user230609 For all $x>0$, you have $$\arctan x=\frac \pi 2 -\arctan \left(\frac 1x\right)$$ You may easily prove this by differentiating both sides.

Comment: Wow...... It's very perfect..

Comment: @user230609 Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For large $n$ we have

> $$ \arctan(n) \sim \frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{n}.  $$

Answer (score 0):

Certainly using a comparison test is easier, but here's what the Alternating Series test requires.

1)  Since the arctangent function has an upper bound of $ \ \frac{\pi}{2} \ $ , it is reasonably clear that $$ \ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ \ \frac{\arctan \ n}{n \ + \ n^{1/2}} \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ , $$

so the series passes the "test for divergence".

2) Differentiating the real function $  \ \frac{\arctan \ x}{x \ + \ x^{1/2}} \ $  gives us

$$ \  \frac{(x \ + \ \sqrt{x}) \ \cdot \ \frac{1}{1 \ + \ x^2} \ - \ \arctan \ x \ \cdot \ ( 1 \ + \ \frac{1}{2 \ \sqrt{x}})}{( \ x \ + \ \sqrt{x} \ )^2}  $$
$$ = \ \ \frac{(x^2 \ + \ x\sqrt{x})  \ - \ \arctan \ x \ \cdot \ ( x \ + \ \frac{1}{2} \ \sqrt{x}) \ (1 \ + \ x^2)}{x \ (1 \ + \ x^2) \ ( \ x \ + \ \sqrt{x} \ )^2}  \ \ . $$

As  $ \ x \ \rightarrow \ \infty\ $ , the denominator grows as $ \ x^5 \ $  , the first term in the numerator as $ \ x^2 \ $ , and the second term as $ \ x^3 \ $ .  Since the arctangent factor only tends to a constant, this derivative will tend to roughly $ \ \frac{1 \ - \ \frac{\pi}{2} \ x}{x^3} \ $ .  So at least beyond some finite value of  $ \ n \ $ , the terms are always decreasing.

So the conditions for alternating-series convergence appear to be satisfied.